# Jupyter Notebook cannot find certain modules

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

As part of a web scraping class I've been instructed to download a few modules from the command terminal (requests, bs4, lxml). These have seemingly been successfully downloaded to my computer, yet my Jupyter Notebook AND PyCharm virtual environment cannot find them.

I am a beginner so I'm sure there are some big things I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Jupyter?
Wich package manager are you using? (eg. what did you type to install the packages?)
Wich modules can it find and which not?

Usually you want to make sure your modules are available in the environment you are using. ( Enviornments are like "versions" of python. You could run multiple versions like 3.7 and 3.9 on your Computer but also also different builds from one python version.)

Pycharm builds its own environment. Make sure you use the enivorment you installed your packages to in Pycharm. Pycharm allows you to modify and create new environments very easily

For PyCharm it might be useful to check out their help page.
I figure this could help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter

The interpreter is basicly the a customized version of python. Pycharm keeps track of the modules you need for every project. So you want to create/select an interpreter which has the packages you have installed.

hope it helps
cheers

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.